# Full changelog of updated packages for Ubuntu releases?

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, release-management

So for any given version e.g. 12.04, 12.10, 13.04,etc. a full changelog of all update packages e.g. MySQL, Apache, etc.?

Note: Raring Ringtail [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes#Updated_Packages) says:

> For a list of all packages being accepted for 13.04 Raring Ringtail, please subscribe to [raring-changes](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/raring-changes).

The [raring changes](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/raring-changes) is a mailing list of nightmare proportions. Maybe there's a final, proofed, easy to understand, changelog of all updated packages?

Comment: Perhaps the blueprints aer the closest - https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+specs otherwise I do not know of a master list.

Comment: Do you want a diff of packages you use or repositories wide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all changelog on http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/, but it's difficult to see.
So the best strategy is to go to http://packages.ubuntu.com, search for interesting packages, and on right column click on "Ubuntu Changelog".
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_logs), has all the latest updates with change-log for all releases.  It gives you Package name, Release, Repository, and when it was Updated, among other information.

[image]

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use `apt-listchanges`, which can display the changelog and NEWS.Debian of packages before upgrading packages.

Something like that should do the trick:

```
apt-get install apt-listchanges
```

Change /etc/apt/listchanges.conf to:

```
[apt]
frontend=text
confirm=1
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=both
```

If you want to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10, you need to change `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Run `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` on the system you want to upgrade.