# CVE-2014-0226 patched?

Tags: 14.04, apache2

We've currently updated to Apache version 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
Can you confirm that this version has been patched for CVE-2014-0226?

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green. This means "[yes, this answer is correct](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)"! **;-)** If there are multiple answers that solve your problem please pick the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information will be (or should be) in the changlog if the given package, to download and view the changelog for apache2 open a Terminal window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

```
apt-get changelog apache2
```

Once it has downloaded the changelog (which should only take a matter of seconds) you will see that the entry for `2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1` states that it fixes the CVE:

> apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1) trusty-security; urgency=medium
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service in mod_proxy
>
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0117.patch: also skip over semicolons in
>       modules/proxy/proxy_util.c.
>   - CVE-2014-0117   * SECURITY UPDATE: resource consumption via mod_deflate body
>       decompression
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0118.patch: added new configuration options
>       DeflateInflateLimitRequestBody, DeflateInflateRatioLimit, and
>       DeflateInflateRatioBurst in modules/filters/mod_deflate.c.
>   - CVE-2014-0118   * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via race in mod_status
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0226.patch: fix race by adding
>       ap_copy_scoreboard_worker() to include/scoreboard.h,
>       modules/generators/mod_status.c, modules/lua/lua_request.c,
>       server/scoreboard.c.
>   - CVE-2014-0226   * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service in mod_cgid
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0231.patch: added new configuration option
>       CGIDScriptTimeout in modules/generators/mod_cgid.c.
>   - CVE-2014-0231
>
>   -- Marc Deslauriers   Mon, 21 Jul 2014
>     15:46:10 -0400

Comment: Another good one!

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information easily! Using the method in [a good answer by @rpadovani](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326185/full-changelog-of-updated-packages-for-ubuntu-releases) leads one to:

http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5/changelog

and a simple search (I used "-0226") gets us to:

```
apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1) trusty-security; urgency=medium

 ...  


 * SECURITY UPDATE: denial of service via race in mod_status
   - debian/patches/CVE-2014-0226.patch: fix race by adding
     ap_copy_scoreboard_worker() to include/scoreboard.h,
     modules/generators/mod_status.c, modules/lua/lua_request.c,
     server/scoreboard.c.
  - CVE-2014-0226
```

Answer (score 1):

On http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/ you can search for CVEs on Ubuntu.

For CVE-2014-0226 that gives you http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0226.html There you see that it's fixed in 14.04 since version 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1